# Complex Event Processing

Tags: event-handling, complex-event-processing

I've recently been looking into event based systems and learned about Complex Event Processing using frameworks such as Apache Storm. I understand that CEP is ideal when you are dealing with large streams of data and you would like to detect certain events among the data and we provide queries to the CEP engine to detect the events.

What about the scenario when the data streams produced every minute are not very large, but instead you have a much larger set of queries that you feed to the CEP? Is CEP still ideal in this scenario? If not, what is the best way to approach it?

Answer (score 0):

Storm is an event processing software that distributes processing tasks on multiple nodes/machines. It is in this sense no *complex* event processing engine since complex means the ability to define more sophisticated events using operators from Event Algebra.

Answer (score 0):

If these queries generate bulk events like batch jobs, then it is probably not the best way for a real-time marketing environment.If we are going to process events, then we should identify them as quickly as possible.

A more suitable approach would be to listen the table for new changes(or new rows) and generate events after every change.

Answer (score -1):

Storm is a distributed real-time computation framework (and is not CEP), see Wikipedia.

A good resource to read up on:
http://www.complexevents.com/2014/08/25/an-overview-of-event-processing-software/

Comment: What is said on the page you are referring to here?